# In CSS, use CSS of other selector

Tags: css

Can I use in one CSS selector the specifications of other selector?

Lets say that I have 3 classes: `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, and I specified `c1`,`c2` like this:

```
.c1 {
    font: some-font;
}

.c2 {
    font-size: some font size;
}
```

And I want `c3` to have all the attributes of `c1` and `c2`.

I know I can do something like this:

```
.c1, .c3 {
    font: some-font;
}

.c2, .c3 {
    font-size: some font size;
}
.c3 {
    font-color: red;
}
```

but this is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a pure CSS solution?

I know that `SASS` could could do that, but is there any other way?

Comment: No, there isn't. BUT here's not point in repeating properties when you could just add multiple classes to the element and get the same effect.

Comment: You can only take advantage of inheritance, so you'd have to add both .c1 and .c2 to your element.  Someday in the future, we'll have variables in CSS.  They are already a part of a draft spec, but they aren't really something the vendors are jumping on board with: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables and here is the spec: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply multiple classes to one set of styles, for example:

```
.c3,
.c1 {
   font: some-font;
}

.c3,
.c2 {
   font-size: some font size;
}
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I would to do that with multiple classes, and that could really inflate the code. I'm looking for another way

Comment: Then I think I misunderstood your question, could you please rephrase it?

Comment: I don't think there is another way without using external tools like LESS.

Answer (score 3):

That wish is - amongst **many** others - a good reason to start using **LESS** **today**.

> http://lesscss.org

Once learnt, you will never go back to vanilla CSS unless someone forces you to. And trust me, it will require **alot** of force.

Comment: Does `LESS` support IE 8? (Unfortunately I have to support it)

Comment: LESS generates to native CSS, so all browsers that understand CSS will work with it.

Comment: That's the thing @Algosub: you write 'cool' code in LESS, and LESS compiles (meaning you'll have to compile it every time you want to test it) it to regular CSS. It does nothing for the filesize in the end, only the LESS code you've written.

Comment: I would also recommend LESS. Also, get an IDE with auto-compile for LESS. You won't regret it I promise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is another way, but this is the way I know:

```
.c1, .c3 {
    font: some-font;
}

.c2, .c3 {
    font-size: some font size;
}
.c3 {
    font-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because you're assuming that `c3` is always a child of `c1` or `c2`.

Comment: Made a mistake in my CSS. I was looking it up to make sure I had it right.